# Loading levels in XNA from XML

Tags: xna, c#, xml

I'm trying to load levels in XNA from XML files.
I have currently got a system to do this working, but it looks like it might get horribly complex as I add more objects later on.
My world currently consists of `Planet` entities along with physics props, scenery, static props, etc. It will later include NPCs, interactive machines, and a *lot* more content (but I want to sort this out before going any further).

Based on a tutorial I read, my level loader loads a `LevelData` entity from XML. This contains arrays of `PlanetLevelData`, `PropData`, and `StaticData`. My test file is as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<XnaContent>

<!-- TODO: replace this Asset with your own XML asset data. -->

    <Asset Type="DataTypes.LevelData">`

        <PlanetData>
            <Item>
                <Position>5.2 5.2</Position>
                <BodyRadius>300</BodyRadius>
                <FieldRadius>450</FieldRadius>
                <Name>Jupiter</Name>
                <Rotation>0</Rotation>
                <ImageName>-</ImageName>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <Position>-2 -2</Position>
                <BodyRadius>300</BodyRadius>
                <FieldRadius>450</FieldRadius>
                <Name>Jupiter2</Name>
                <Rotation>0</Rotation>
                <ImageName>-</ImageName>
            </Item>
        </PlanetData>

        <PropData>
            <Item>
            <Type>Crate</Type>
            <Position>2 3</Position>
            </Item>
        </PropData>

        <StaticData>
            <Item>
                <Type>FromImage</Type>
                <Position>-4.5 -4.5</Position>
                <ImagePath>Lamp</ImagePath>
                <Rotation>2</Rotation>
                <Radius>0</Radius>
                <Vertices></Vertices>
                <PlanetOwner>Jupiter2</PlanetOwner>
            </Item>
        </StaticData>

    </Asset>

</XnaContent>
```

In other words, I have to put *all* my content files into arrays. However, for me to have different types of `StaticData` from the XML file, I have to specify the type with a String (called `Type`).

I then load the XML using `Content.Load<LevelData>("name here.xml")`. I go through every `PlanetData` in the array and create a new `Planet` based on it's properties. I also use switch statements based on the `Type` field to specify which type to create...

Is this the only way to load level data into objects using XML (I hope not, it's hideous to use). I couldn't really find much on this topic...

Comment: I'm planning on writing my own level editor. I just want a way of loading the objects easily from a file...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use XML files as content files in XNA?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11230/how-to-use-xml-files-as-content-files-in-xna)

Comment: Are you sure XML is the best way? You know you could save a lot of space by using binary formats.

Comment: user1306322: If you include your XML file in the content project, it will compile it into a compressed binary format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content project supports XML files, and it uses a special type of serializer called IntermediateSerializer, which is better suited for game data than XmlSerializer.

No need to read your PlanetData and figure out how to convert it to a Planet, you can directly serialize a Planet and have it seamlessly loaded at runtime. In your editor, you can create a Planet object and serialize it to XML:

```
Planet Jupiter = new Planet();
Jupiter.Position = new Vector2(5.2, 5.2);
Jupiter.BodyRadius = 300;
Jupiter.FieldRadius = 450;
Jupiter.Name = "Jupiter";
Jupiter.Rotation = 0;

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;

using( XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create( "Jupiter.xml", settings ) )
{
    IntermediateSerializer.Serialize( writer, Jupiter, null );
}
```

This serializes an individual Planet object called Jupiter.xml that you can load with your content manager just like you would load a texture or a model. Include it in your content project and call the following code at runtime:

```
Planet jupiter = contentManager.Load<Planet>( "Jupiter" );
```

If you want to serialize a single Level object containing all of your actors, just fill out your Level class with its members and serialize the Level object in the same fashion. When you load the Level object it will already be filled with all of the appropriate objects.

Shawn Hargreaves has an excellent series of posts on the IntermediateSerializer, under the "IntermediateSerializer" heading:

http://www.shawnhargreaves.com/blogindex.html

Comment: Cool! I'll have to check out the link you provide because I'm not fully understanding what you did there but this looks like a pretty good alternative to my option though both answers would definitely get the job done.

Comment: If you serialize your data, add/remove properties to your objects, and de-serialize, does it break the deserialization?

Comment: Yes, it breaks the deserialization, which has caused me plenty of headaches. For new variables, you can get around it by putting the attribute [ContentSerializerAttribute( Optional = true )] on the new variable. Removing variables still makes me re-serialize all my content.

Comment: This looks really good, but how do you load polymorphic data? For example if I had `ElectricalAppliance` as a subclass of `PhysicsProp`, how would I load that from an xml file?

Comment: It handles polymorphism seamlessly; just do it like I did in the original post. IntermediateSerializer outputs the type of the class. You should never have to touch the XML yourself, IntermediateSerializer is very robust.

Answer (score 5):

There may be a way to do this with the content pipeline, but I have done it without and instead used standard XML Serialization.

The approach I am about to show is just one way you can structure your data and may or may not be relevent to what you are trying to accomplish. My goal with this answer is to provide you enough direction so that you will be able to create your own level structure and apply it to your game.

To start with I have an XML file in my content project that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Screen>
    <TileSet Width="16" Height="16">
      <Tiles>
        <Tile GroupId="G" TileId="1" TextureName="Generic" Path="tempSprites/Terrain" X="9" Y="3" />
        <Tile GroupId="G" TileId="2" TextureName="Generic" Path="tempSprites/Terrain" X="10" Y="3" />
        <Tile GroupId="G" TileId="3" TextureName="Generic" Path="tempSprites/Terrain" X="11" Y="3" />
      </Tiles>        
    </TileSet>
    <ScreenDefinition Width="40" Height="24" BaseGroup="G">
      <TileReferences>
        <TileReference Id="G2" X="0" Y="0" />
        <TileReference Id="G3" X="15" Y="0" />
        <TileReference Id="G2" X="15" Y="15" />
        <TileReference Id="G3" X="0" Y="15" />
      </TileReferences>
    </ScreenDefinition>
  </Screen>
```

All XML Attributes and sub elements you see are properties within the object class.

So following this, Screen is our root elemment and is a class within my project. This class contains a TileSet object property and a ScreenDefinition object property. The code for this class is as follows:

```
[XmlRoot()]
[Serializable]
public class Screen
{
    public Screen()
    {
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public TileSet TileSet;
    [XmlElement]
    public ScreenDefinition ScreenDefinition;
}
```

TileSet looks something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class TileSet
{
    public TileSet()
    {
    }

    [XmlArray]
    public List<Tile> Tiles { get; set; }

    private int width = 0;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Width
    {
        get { return width; }
        set { width = value; }
    }

    private int height = 0;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Height
    {
        get { return height; }
        set { height = value; }
    }
}
```

The key part of this class is the `[XmlArray]` attribute on the Tiles property. This is what helps define that object to be deserialized into a collection of Tile objects when loaded.

The rest of the data classes I will not show because they follow the same general pattern that you have seen here with these two classes.

To implement this it is incredibly painless. First you need to do some configuration to your XML file so that its not processed by the content pipeline.

1. In Solution Explorer, click your XML file
2. From the properties window, Set the Build Action property to "None"
3. From the properties window, set the Copy to Output Directory property to either "Copy always" or "Copy if new" (whatever fits your needs)

This sets us up so that you can access the XML file right from the file system. Assuming you added the XML file to a Content project the file will be in the `bin/Content/Your/Folder/Structure/Here` folder.

Now you are ready to actually load the data from the file, and its as easy as this:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Screen));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
Screen screen = (Screen)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Anywhere you see the type "Screen" is going to be what you've defined as your root element in your XML file and in code (see the `XmlRoot()` attribute on the Screen class).

And with all of this you should be able to dynamically load all your XML data into objects at run time. The data setup can be tedious depending on your data structure but it works really well once you learn the ins and outs and all the caveats of serialization.

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately my game is not even remotely tile-based...

Comment: Tiles have absolutely nothing to do with it. This concept can be applied to any sort of data structure. I explained these concepts in enough detail where you should be able to apply it to whatever your situation is. I am only going to provide you with an example. I will not write your code for you.

Comment: Sorry! I read this over in detail, and this looks _incredibly_ useful, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: So, the `Tile` class will have `[XmlAttribute] public char GroupId {get and set code}`, am I right?

Comment: Yup. I actually just used strings but the concept is the same :)

Comment: Wait, with this method is it possible to load derived classes?

Comment: You might have to get more detailed with your specific use case, but I can confirm that using [XmlArrayItem] approach on this answer worked for me and loaded a child of Tile into my TileSet.Tiles list. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1643424/780148

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it skips the content pipeline and reads directly from files on your OS. The Xbox can't do that, so this approach will only work on Windows. XmlSerializer also outputs bloated XML and doesn't handle polymorphism well. I strongly suggest you use IntermediateSerializer because the XNA team wrote it to make up for the shortcomings of XmlSerializer. Check out Shawn Hargreaves' post here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/07/28/intermediateserializer-vs-xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: I don't disagree that the IntermediateSerializer is a good way to go. I am supportive of using the content pipeline if desirable, but this approach is also valid. Many ways to skin a cat right? Also, from the exact article you linked to it states: "But there are also situations where XmlSerializer would be a better choice: Works on Xbox, so you can use it at runtime as well as during your content build; More flexible attributes for controlling whether data appears as an XML element or attribute; Supports XML schemas; Supports SOAP" - It's really all a matter of what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

There's definitely ways to make this a lot less tedious.

1. Your level file should describe the entities and their relationships in the world, so that when you deserialize the XML through ContentManager.Load, you get a Level instance that is ready to use. No additional processing needed.
2. The reason you find it tedious is because you are MANUALLY adding all the content in the XML file. What you should be doing instead is simply adding all the stuff in the editor like usual and then simply let the IntermediateSerializer do the work for you when you save the level.

   ```
   var xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
   {
           Indent = true,
           IndentChars = "\t",
           NewLineChars = "\n"
   };

   var destinationFileName = "[DestionFilename]";
   using (var outputFile = XmlWriter.Create(destinationFileName, xmlSettings))
   {
           IntermediateSerializer.Serialize<SceneGraph>(outputFile, scene, destinationFileName);
   }
   ```

This can then be loaded using step1.

NOTE: The SceneGraph above is my "Level".

UPDATE:

@WilliamOsborne They are loaded like any other object. InterMediateSerializer automatically adds the Type attribute when serializing and loads the appropriate type when deserializing.

Assume that your Galaxy has a list of astronomical objects in a list:

```
    class AstronomicalObject { .. }         //Base class
    class Planet : AstronomicalObject { .. }
    class Asteroid : AstronomicalObject { .. }

    class Galaxy
    {
        public List<AstronimicalObject> AstronomicalObjects
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

When the Galaxy is serialized the output will look something like this:

```
    ...
        <AstronomicalObjects>
            <Item Type="Planet">...</Item>
            <Item Type="Planet">...</Item>
            <Item Type="Asteroid">...</Item>
        </AstronomicalObjects>
    ...
```

Comment: What about derived classes? How would I load those in XML?

Comment: @WilliamOsborne I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: I found the answer on Shawn Hargreaves' site, but thanks anyway!